# Don't match only spaces

Tags: regex

I have the following regexp that matches underscores, letters, numbers, and spaces. My problem is that I don't want to match strings with only spaces. Any help? Thanks!

`[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first character must be a non-space then this will do:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*
```

If you need to be able to match leading spaces as well:

```
\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*
```

Comment: @gonzoc0ding Hmm, try adding another slash in front of the `\s`? I'm not sure what you're working with/in and what needs escaping and what doesn't. If you could give us a sample string and/or the environment you're using that would help!

Comment: @TheZ just change your regex to be generic not Language Specific (i.e change your `\\s` to `\s`

Answer (score 1):

[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*

There are more elegant ways to phrase this, but I don't know if your tool of choice supports it.